# Get real value of jQuery-Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I need the "real" value from my select-box used with jquery-autocomplete like this...

I got the whole function from http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

So, for now I've changed this:

```
select: function( event, ui ) {
   ui.item.option.selected = true;
   that._trigger( "selected", event, {
       item: ui.item.option
   });
},
```

to...

```
select: function(event, ui) {
   var selectedObj = ui.item;
   alert(selectedObj.value);
},
```

My "original" select-box looks like:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <select id="combobox" onclick="">
        <option value="0">...</option>
        <option value="value_i_want_to_get" >Text</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

So if I change the select I got the "Text" from my alert `alert(selectedObj.value);` but I need the value of the option, not the text.

Could anybody please help me?

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
$(this).find("option:value").text()
```

Answer (score 0):

The selected option is already provided as a parameter to the `select` function as `ui.item.option`, so the value attribute of the selected option can be accessed with:

```
console.log(ui.item.option.value);
```

or the text accessed with

```
console.log(ui.item.option.text);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's it andyb!
This works for me:

```
select: function(event, ui) {
   var selectedObj = ui.item.option.value;
   alert(selectedObj);
},
```

Thank you!